# Restore or access workspaces from MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Using MySQL Workbench 6.3.8 build 1228 CE (64-bit), on Windows 10 Pro, version 1803, build 17134.112.

I want to restore my old workspaces in MySQL Workbench. If that is not possible, I will be happy with just being able to access them as text files.

I guess my laptop had an unusual power-off or reset last night. Normally I put it in Sleep mode, but when I opened it this morning it had reset itself: all applications had quit.

I re-opened Workbench, and got this error message:

[image: this error message]

saying that my workspaces could not be opened.

I can't get the full text of the error message, so I don't know exactly where Workbench is looking, but using Windows Explorer I could navigate to:

```
C:\Users\JamesBarton\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\sql_workspaces
```

which looks right to me, and contains `.workspace` and `.autosave` directories.

I've backed up the `Workbench\` directory, and then tried just removing the `.autosave` directories, to force the use of the `.workspace` directories, but when I did that, Workbench still just opened one empty tab. The first `.workspace` directory contains 95 files, including 45 `.scratch` files totalling 107kb.

Is it possible to check exactly where MySQL Workbench is looking for workspaces?

Can I force it to open a workspace directly, or at least show me why it can't open a workspace? If that is not possible, can I somehow extract the SQL from the `.scratch` files? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy to recover the sql from the scratch files which are just plain text files. The sql code is not encrypted. Also you can look in the Workbench log file (see Help menu) to see if there's an error message or similar for a specific file. Could be there's some file corruption. Running the file system checker on that disk also might help.

PS: in Windows you can use the clipboard in system dialogs like this one. Just press Ctrl+C while the dialog has the focus to copy the entire text, including the button captions, to the clipboard. That will hopefully give you the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Even though my desktop has crashed several times in the past 3 years (either power-related or system) this last time was the first time MySQL Workbench had issues with a workspace (apparently the 2 I had open at the time?). When I investigated why I discovered that all the `.info` and `.scratch` files in those workspaces were written with only `NUL` characters so no easy recovery of my tabs is possible. Grrr.

I will have to recover everything from scratch (haha) by going through the `sql_history` and possibly `log` folders and copy/paste as necessary back into the GUI.